# field a colums with the substring of the namefile in DataFlow

Tags: mapping, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I want to field a colums name ManagingCountryCode with the name of File , this colums existe just in my Output (BD)
I've try to do a substring like that but always wrong!

I chose an option to store the fileName in a colums 
[

Comment: I have 3 files(x1,x2,x3) with the same shema in the same file X in blob storage i import the file X like input i want to add a colums (fileName) and filedIt with the NamesFiles (x1,x2,x3) after that with derived colums i can map fileName to colums Y  with a substring so in my Y  will have (1,2,3) ..hope that more clear .

Comment: Can you click "validate" and copy & paste the validation error that expression is giving? Also, what do your file names look like? Can you share some examples? Are you trying to get just the file name without the file extension?

Comment: Yes just Name my files  concerne different country and  the name of file contains this information so in the coulums Country I want to put the substring split of(NameFile) but first i must to define the colum fileName and i do not know hwo!

Comment: I found an option where i can chose to store my fileName in colums but i don t know how to add it

Answer (score 1):

like i say, i store the filesName in filenamecolum which is an option in (SourceOption) after that i did'nt get the error below(in picture) because he can define what is 'fileName' , after that i add mapping simple and i mapp the new colums with the others in output file.